# How can I sort a PHP multidimensional array by the value of one of its keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array of database values.  The titles are stored in language files, so I cannot simply order the db query by title.I have to loop through the results and get the title from a language file based on the id of the category.  Because of this, I have to create a custom array with the appropriate title.

This is from my model:

```
<?php
function retrieve(){

    foreach($query_cats->result_array() as $cat){

        $info[] = array(
            'id' => $cat['id'],
            'title' => $this->lang->line('cat_'.$cat['id']),
            'slug' => $cat['slug'],
            'icon' => $cat['icon']
        );

    }

    return $info;

}
```

Is there a php function that will allow me to sort the $info array by the value of the title key?  I wasn't sure how I could do this with asort($info) since the array is more complicated.

Comment: An example of an unsorted array and the sorted version would be more useful.

Comment: Use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)? Here are the different PHP sorting functions: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Read about [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). It is the answer to your problem. The documentation contains even the code you could use (in Example #3). Apparently that example was written before the function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) was introduced (in PHP 5.5). [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) is, of course, another possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Not sure if this what you want, But you could dige more in this function 
[array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)
or use the following example to make you own code.

```
$title= array();
foreach ($info as $key => $row)
{
    $title[$key] = $row['title'];
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $info);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in combination with [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php). I also propose a simplification in the loop in your function:

```
function retrieve(){
    foreach ($query_cats->result_array() as $cat) {
        $cat['title'] = $this->lang->line('cat_'.$cat['id']);
        $info[] = $cat;
    }
    usort($info, function($a, $b) {
        return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    });
    return $info;
}
```